# what does 이런거 자주올려주세요 mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

이런거 means 'this', right? 
I may be completely wrong though...

but what on earth does 자주올려주세요 mean?
올려다 means upload right?
자주 means often, right?
주세요 is please.. so are they asking me to do upload something more often?

I was wondering if 이런거 자주올려주세요 meant 'Upload this more often' or telling me to upload pictures on my social media more(this is where this term was used)? Can someone translate it properly for me?

Comment: 이런거 => things like these; 거 = 것 = thing, 이런 => these, like these

Comment: The canonical form of '올려' is '올리다', not '올려다', where '올려' is '올리-' + '-어'.

Answer (score 2):

이런 거 자주올려주세요 means 'please upload this kind of thing more often'.

이런 거 means 'this kind of thing' or 'something like this'.